# How can I pivot a dataframe's column labels to form a data column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with a column labels that I want to move into a data column, reshaping and ignoring index values.

```
import pandas as pd

before = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0:['A',1,2,3],
                             1: ['B',4,5,6],
                             2: ['C',7,8,9],
                             3: ['D',10,11,12]},
                            columns=['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                            orient='index')

before
  C0  C1  C2  C3
0  A   1   2   3
1  B   4   5   6
2  C   7   8   9
3  D  10  11  12

after
    0   1   2
0   A  C1   1
1   A  C2   2
2   A  C3   3
3   B  C1   4
4   B  C2   5
5   B  C3   6
6   C  C1   7
7   C  C2   8
8   C  C3   9
9   D  C1  10
10  D  C2  11
11  D  C3  12
```

I've tried to `df.pivot()` without success as the column labels don't figure into `df.pivot()` only row and column data.

Is there some way I can achieve this without loops?

Comment: Use `stack`: `before.set_index('C0').stack().reset_index()`, `pivot` is for the opposite.

Comment: or `melt` : ``before.melt('C0')``

Comment: yeah done. They're both excellent solutions. melt() because I didn't even know about this function and stack() I've never really understood it. Should I just choose the most succinct one, melt?

Comment: Could whoever upvoted stack() please give a reason why it's preferred?

Comment: @sammywemmy please submit as answer and I'll accept